# Error en el gradle de android studio "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification "

Tags: java, android, gradle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el mensaje de error:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less...
>   (Ctrl+F1)Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or
>   tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One
>   such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android
>   support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a
>   version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: puedes poner la configuracion de gradle para ayudarte de mejor forma

Comment: Realmente es un error muy común, esto te servira [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es tener las dependencias actualizados de acuerdo a la versión definida en  `compileSdkVersion` en tu archivo `build.gradle`.

Puedes configurar las versiones adecuadas de las dependencias posicionando el puntero y mediante la secuencia de teclas <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, te mostrará la versión adecuada.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

--

Para el caso de la library de compatibilidad que se subraya en rojo, indica que alguna dependencia, por ejemplo "GSON" puede no estar utilizando las versiones de soporte usadas por tu proyecto principal, esto puede aunque no necesariamente causar problemas.